# Flagging "didn't downvote" comments that came with constructive criticism

Tags: support, comments, flags, declined-flags

I was pretty confident that comments with "didn't downvote" statements should be removed. Well, I flagged such a comment as *"Didn't downvote statement"*, but it got declined.

Probably because of the criticism that was also in that comment.
Should I refrain from flagging "didn't downvote" comments if they came with constructive criticism?

**EDIT**

Apologies, but I did neglect to acknowledge that the constructive criticism was indeed outdated, so flagging as *"No longer needed"* was the key. I didn't know that at the time.

Comment: Why do such comments need to be flagged? Are they no longer needed? Unfriendly? Rude? If it's none of those, then there is little reason to flag them, especially if they still provide relevant information (so, **not** "no longer needed").

Comment: @VLAZ Quote from Cody Gray: *It is not necessary, and borderline inappropriate. No one should discuss their votes. I either delete these comments or edit out the portion about votes. – Cody Gray♦*

Comment: @VLAZ So even if they don't get removed, flagging them will allow users to edit out the portion. And to answer your question of *"Are they no longer needed? Unfriendly? Rude?"*, please read my post. I specified that *"I flagged such a comment as "Didn't downvote statement""*

Comment: "*flagging them will allow users to edit out the portion*" flags go directly to moderators. Most of the time a user will never know there was a flag raised against their comment. That is unless there the flags point to a very severe problem - *then* a mod might contact them. However, users are not notified for any non-critical flags - neither for the flags being raised, nor the flags being handled either way. At best, the user might notice a comment of theirs is gone but that's not necessary to happen due to a flag or due to a moderator handling it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: "This question's topic is only applicable to one specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should relate to features or policies that commonly apply to the network ...", take up Cody's advice on their meta; you are in no way at the place where you need to escalate this to the main meta. **Only** if you have an appeal of a complaint on a child meta would you bring it to the main meta; unless it's a systemic problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Should I refrain from flagging "didn't downvote" comments if they came with constructive criticism?

Since this is one of the [intended purposes of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;

unless the post has been edited to address that criticism, the comment is useful and it should **not** be flagged. "Didn't downvote" may be noise, but it's not unfriendly or so. I can understand why a moderator would edit it out, but (especially given the large number of flags on Stack Overflow) it's IMHO not something worth flagging for.